# Redshift : How to keep \ as a part of string at Copy Command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, escaping, amazon-redshift

We'd like to import \ as part of data into Redshift table (Since it's same with our currency mark, Japanese yen).

As you know, Redshift handles \ as default escape, so, usually we replace \ to \\ and we can import \ as part of string into the tables.

ex. \365  --> \\365

But this time, we need to import very huge file, over 25GB and found out it consumes huge memory to replace \ to \\ as usual.

So I'm wondering we can use ESCAPE option in COPY command, for example, ESCAPE '^', to use other word as escape, instead of default escape , but it doesn't work so far.

Is there any better idea, kindly let me know.
Thank you.

--

Let me add the actual command and error message. Maybe something wrong in the combination of the copy options.

```
-- Command (Executed from Workbench/J 

copy $[VarODS_DB]."$[VarODS_Table]" 
from $[VarS3FileName]
$[VarIAM]

--REMOVEQUOTES
--IGNOREHEADER 2
--CSV
GZIP
DATEFORMAT 'auto'
TIMEFORMAT 'auto'
DELIMITER ',' 
ACCEPTINVCHARS '?' 
COMPUPDATE TRUE 
STATUPDATE TRUE 
MAXERROR 0 
TRUNCATECOLUMNS  
NULL AS '\000' 
EXPLICIT_IDS
ESCAPE '^'
;

--Error Message
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "'^'"  
Position: 1311; [SQL State=42601, DB Errorcode=500310] 
In file: C:\temp\test.sql
```

Comment: Are you importing a single file, or many files?

Comment: @Max Ganz II Thanks for prompt comment. In this case, only one file, we need to adjust.

Comment: Redshift is a Big Data system.  That means the ETL system needs to handle Big Data.  IME, all data going into Redshift needs pre-processing outside of Redshift, before loading.  I would advise you to create a Big Data capable ETL system, for example, I used to use EMR to pre-process data (although there are certain issues with this, to do with files not always turning up in S3).  Ideally, this would also move you away from loading a single large file, which is absolutely the wrong way to load data into Redshift.

Comment: @Max Ganz II  Thanks again for your variable advice. I never use EMR, but I'll try it :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, removing the escape character as \ will make backslash no longer a special character.  It will be read just like any other character. To do this remove the ESCAPE parameter from the COPY command.

Now, if you are using backslash as an escape character in other locations in your file(s) you will have just moved the problem.  If not, then you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it can't work as I expected. I expected ESCAPE '^' means '^' is working as escape character, instead of \ , but I got syntax error.

Comment: @Sachiko Please Edit your Question to show us the command you used and the _exact_ error message returned, so that we can try it ourselves.

Comment: Reviewed the RS docs and updated the answer.

Comment: @John Rotenstein Thanks again for your advice, John. I added the command and error message. If you will find something, please let me advice again.

Comment: ESCAPE option of the COPY command doesn't take a parameter.  It is just a switch. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-escape

Comment: @Bill Weiner Thanks for your valuable information again, Bill. Oh...so we can't use other word for escape in copy command. I see. Thanks a lot for your advice.